# Operator overload of << needs const; produces headache

Tags: c++, visual-c++, operator-overloading, logic

I am trying to overload `operator <<`, but it always need to be a `const` function.  However, I want to change values inside this overloaded function.  How do I do this?

**EDIT1:** The code stub is something like below:

```
class Check

{   
public:
    void operator << (boost::any)
    {
        // checks weather the given is hresult,string(filename) or int(line no) 
        // and dump them into the exception object, 
        // There by hresult will initiate the object and int will throw the object.
        // so the input order must be like below
    }
private:
    Exception exception;
};
```

Usage

```
Check   check;
check << file->open << __FILE__ << __LINE__ ;
```

**EDIT2:** This is for who ever said that the syntax is not good to implement
  I am not a well exp. programmer. I just tried to make a quick solution for exception. My motive is it shouldn't consume more time, it should be easy to type. Because my colleagues have to use this exception class. I tried to find a solution for that, and the answer came as  << operator overloading. For example consider the below sample

1) My Method

```
#define INFO __LINE__ << __FILE__
c++
RunAndCheck runAndCheck;

try
{
    runAndCheck << checkVersion() << INFO;
    runAndCheck << file->Open() << INFO;
    runAndCheck << file->rename() << INFO;
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

2) Traditional method

```
#define INFO __FILE__,__LINE__
try
{
    runAndCheck.check(checkVersion(),INFO);
    runAndCheck.check(file->Open(),INFO);
    runAndCheck.check(file->rename(),INFO);
}
catch(...)
{
}
```

May be in this stub it will be more or less same, but consider a situation where win32API used. There every call must be checked for exception. In that case, I found << overloading is easy to type. So that I made such a syntax

Comment: Can you provide some more detail about what you're trying to do?  Also, you probably shouldn't be changing anything in `operator <<` unless you're implementing a stream class; is there a particular reason you need to?

Comment: Might i suggest some aspirin  ? Also please let us know why you want to modify the input when using '<<'

Comment: Please post your code or a minimalistic sample and exact error you are getting.

Comment: Take two aspirin and post your code, then come back in the morning.

Comment: If this class works the way I think it does, you'd probably be better off replacing the whole class with a simple function: `Check(HRESULT, char const*, int)`. If not that, then at least get rid of `boost::any` and just write three separate `operator<<` overloads for the three parameter types you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're likely doing something wrong then.  Post the relevant bits of your code, along with a better summary of what your trying to do, and you'll get more help.

That being said, if you need to modify some data in a const object, there are a couple things you can do:

1. Declare the member you want to modify `mutable`.
2. Use `const_cast<...>(...)` to remove the const modifier from the passed in object.

But most likely you're trying to do something the wrong way.

Answer (score 7):

`operator<<` doesn't need to be a const function.

Your real problem, though, appears to be the void return type.  In order to chain insertions together, you need to return `*this`.

Comment: The problem discussed here is not related to your hint . But, it helped me a lot especially when I got "void lvalue". Thank you for it

Answer (score 5):

The reason you're having trouble here is that this is an inappropriate use of operator overloading.  Operator overloading is best used in these spots:

1. Your type acts like a built-in type (for example, a mathematical type, array, or pointer), and you want to support the built-in operators on your type.
2. Your type needs to support copying, in which case you should implement `operator =`.
3. Your type needs to interface with a standard library like the STL or streams, in which case you might need to implement `operator <<` for stream insertion or `operator <` to store your type in the standard container classes.
4. You want to implement a function object, in which case you should implement `operator ()`.

The code you have above does not fall into any of these categories, and consequently any use of it is likely to confuse people.  For example, if someone not well-versed with your project sees something like this:

```
myCheck << myValue;
```

They are likely to be thinking "oh, that's some sort of stream insertion" or "oh, that's a mathematical type getting bit-shifted over."  However, in your case this code really means "have the checker object `myCheck` validate `myValue`."  If that's what you want to do, then write something more explicit like

```
myCheck.validate(myValue);
```

Now, someone looking over your code can get a much better sense for how it works and what it's trying to do.

In general, think about the Principle of Least Astonishment when writing code - code shouldn't surprise you about how it works.  By using `operator <<` in a nonstandard context, you are likely to cause programmers to misinterpret your code or have a hard time understanding what it does.  Being more explicit about your intentions by using named functions rather than overloaded operators in this and related contexts makes the code more readable and decreases the chance that the code will trip up people reading it.

Now, as for an actual answer to your question.  There is no requirement that `operator <<` be a `const` member function.  Think about the standard streams classes like `cout` or `ofstream`; the operation

```
cout << "Hello, world!" << endl;
```

Certainly modifies `cout` by pushing new data into it, just as the operation

```
cout << setfill('0') << left << hex;
```

Modifies `cout` by changing the formatting flags.  So, if you want your `operator <<` function to mutate the object the data is pushed into, by all means go ahead and make it a non-`const` member function.  C++ doesn't have any expectations about the `const`ness or non-`const`ness of any overloaded operators, so you should be perfectly fine.

Comment: It sure looks to me like stream insertion, just as much as say a stringstream, which also puts the operand into a memory buffer.

Comment: #4 is a special case of #1.  "Acts like a function."

Answer (score 0):

You're implementing `operator<<` as an inserter into our `Check` object here. In this case, it looks like the right solution is to just have your insertion operator actually be non-const, since it would be nonsensical to use it on a `const` object (because it's mutating logical object state).