# C++what is the type of the __FILE__ macro

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, logic

I am trying to create an exception class. For this I overloaded the `<<` operator. So the code is something like this

```
class RunAndCheck
{
     opearator << (boost::any given)
     {

         //Here goes the value of the    "given"

     }
};
```

The usage is like this

```
RunAndCheck s;
s << file->open() << __FILE__ << __LINE__ ;
```

So the problem is that I want to know the type of the **FILE**, then only I can extract the string out of `boost::any`. Can anybody invoke your curiosity around this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

__FILE__ expands into a string literal, just as if you had written "/path/to/current/file.cpp" directly.  String literals are non-modifiable char array lvalues.

You want to template that << instead of using boost::any:

```
class RunAndCheck {
public:
    template<class T>
    RunAndCheck& operator<<(const T& value) {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Or you want to provide overloads for all the acceptable types:

```
class RunAndCheck {
public:
    RunAndCheck& operator<<(const char* value) {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
    RunAndCheck& operator<<(int value) {
        // ...
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: I have to use some if else conditions based on the type, like if(the input is no) cout << " line no " << no, if(is string) cout << " file name " << fileName. Can you say how to achieve that?

Comment: @prabhakaran: Make sure you look at visitor's answer.  Even though I resolved the syntax/type problem you asked about, the other is the correct semantic solution.

Answer (score 8):

Macros do not have types, they are just text replacements made by the preprocessor (without type checks). The type of the value dropped in by `__FILE__` is a constant C string.

Comment: @jdehaan  Can you explain me further. Is C String means CString or some other

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: const char* is incorrect, though you can get that from a string literal.

Comment: a C string is not a class. it is a const literal, exactly if you typed `"c:\path\file.cpp"` directly into the source code. The type of that string literal is `const char[]`.

Comment: @tenfour: technically, its type is (equivalent to) `char[]` for historical reasons, though it should always be treated as if it were `const`.

Comment: Saying "macros do not have types" is less than useful. The value that a macro expands to has a type, just as all values do.

Comment: @Jim, good remark, that is indirectly what I meant. @Stephane, thanks for the precision, I forgot to express that clearly too.

Comment: Actually, I should clarify that -- the value that a macro expands to has a type, _if_ it expands to a value ... of course, macros can expand to all sorts of syntax other than values. `__FILE__`, however, expands to a value.

Answer (score 5):

`__FILE__` is replaced by a string literal, whose type is

```
const char[length_of_particular_string]
```

You should really reconsider what you are doing. (Opinion also based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062699/c-operator-overload-of-needs-const-produces-headache).)

Firstly, boost::any is no good for such usage (in particular since the type of the string literal will be different in different cases). But even if not for the technical difficulties, you should use normal function overloading.

More importantly, it seems that the functionality that you want is to receive a boolean value and throw an error containing the file name and line number if the value is not true. Since you always require all 3 components (although according to your description it would be possible to have it throw without giving it the file name, or have the class do nothing useful), a function that takes those 3 arguments makes more sense.

Furthermore, you can now wrap calls to this in a macro, so that the file name and line number are automatically provided.

Full example:

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

void check_result(bool result, const char* line, int line_number)
{
    if (!result) {
        //for example:
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << line << ' ' << line_number;
        throw std::runtime_error(ss.str()); 
    } 
} 

#define CALL_AND_CHECK(expression) check_result((expression), __FILE__, __LINE__)

bool foobar(bool b) { return b; }

int main()
{
    try {
        CALL_AND_CHECK(foobar(true));
        CALL_AND_CHECK(foobar(false));
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good advice, but you might want to change \_\_LINE\_\_ to \_\_FILE\_\_. :)

Comment: see that previous question's new edit ("stackoverflow.com/questions/5062699/…;).