# What is the type of the __LINE__ macro in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, logic

What is the type of the `__LINE__` macro in C++?

Comment: its a preprocessor numerical constant.

Comment: @aaa I want to know it's type explicitly, like int,int *,etc.

Comment: It has no explicit type, because it's preprocessor constant. Every occurence of _ _LINE_ _ is changed to actual value before compilation, so before there are types at all.

Comment: @Pawel constants have types too

Comment: You still haven't given up abusing operator<< (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062699/c-operator-overload-of-needs-const-produces-headache)? What's going to be your next problem: what do I do when the type of `file->open` is the same as the type of `__LINE__` in `check << file->open << __FILE__ << __LINE__ ;`

Comment: @David: It has the same type as '2' or any other hardcoded number and it is assumed during usage. In `char line = __ LINE __;` it will be `char` and in `long long line = __ LINE __;` it will be `long long`. Constants are changed to their values before compiling, so before any type exists.

Comment: @Pawel What about if the constants are placed in expressions? Or passed to procedures?

Comment: @David: `const int` is assumed from what I remember.

Comment: @Pawel No you are changing your story!  ;-)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C++03 §16.8p1:

> __LINE__ The line number of the current source line (a decimal constant).

This will either be int, or if INT_MAX (which is allowed to be as little as 32,767) is not big enough (… I won't ask …), then it will be long int.  If it would be bigger than LONG_MAX, then you have undefined behavior, which, for once, is not a problem worth worrying about in a file of at least 2,147,483,647 lines (the minimum allowed value for LONG_MAX).

The same section also lists other macros you may be interested in.

Comment: @prabhakaran: Link to what?  The standard or drafts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: @prabhakaran: `HRESULT` is a typedef, not a seperate and distinct type. In particular, it's a typedef for a numerical type. You can convert 37 to a HRESULT. Now, that 37 could also occur because you had a `__LINE__` macro on line 37.

Comment: As you said the __LINE__ macro's type is int. But due to the fact that I had a over loaded function which took long as its argument, my int receiving overloaded function can't get any chance. I forgot the sequence of operator overloading argument match. Now I corrected the functions. Thank you for your reply

Comment: @MSalters Yes,you are exactly correct, thank you for your correction. My above comment tells the fact exactly.

Comment: What if I have a source file with 2,147,483,647 lines? (Okay, I'm kidding :P)

Comment: @NathanOsman: You'd need one more, to make 2,147,483,648. However, I'm more worried about #line directive abuse, but more != greatly.

Answer (score 5):

The C++ standard simply has this to say:

> `__LINE__`: The presumed line number (within the current source file) of the current source line (an integer constant).

It does not actually state the type so it's most likely going to be the same type as an unadorned integer would be in your source code which would be an `int`. The fact that the upper end of the allowed range is `2G - 1` supports that (even though the lower range is `1`).

The fact that `#line` only allows digits (no trailing `U` to make it unsigned) can also be read to support this.

But, that's only *support.* I couldn't find a definitive statement within either the C++ or C standards. It just makes sense<sup>*a</sup> that it will be translated into something like `42` when it goes through the preprocessing phase and that's what the compiler will see, treating it exactly like `42` (an `int`).

---

<sup>*a</sup>: This wouldn't be the first time my common sense was wrong, though :-)

Comment: The definitive statement for the type of decimal constants is in C++03 §2.13.1p2, which says either int or long int here.

Comment: Yes, but it's not necessarily a decimal constant, which is why I was reticent to make a pronouncement. It seems to me that a conforming implementation could convert `__LINE__` into `42U` and still be kosher. I don't have C++03 handy but C++0x where I sourced my stuff from states "integer constant" and that includes U, L, UL, LL and ULL types.

Comment: C++03 exactly says "a decimal constant".

Comment: @Fred: don't get me wrong, I'm sure you're right and it translates to the banal `42` - it's just my sources were unclear on the matter :-)

Comment: @Fred: Although "decimal constant" is defined in C++03 only indirectly, by non-normative footnote 21, which refers to C89. In C++ `42` is a *decimal-literal*, and `42U` is not a *decimal-literal*, it's an *integer-literal*. In C `42` is a decimal constant, and `42U` isn't. So the intent is clear, but paxdiablo is right that they messed up the wording in C++03. 16.8/1 should have said "decimal literal", I think, but they've copied C without changing it. If in C++0x they've changed it to "integer constant", that's interesting because presumably that *can* be `42U`, a breaking change.

Comment: @Steve: Don't forget C is a normative reference for C++. But I don't see how what you said changes "but it's not necessarily a decimal constant" => "C++03 exactly says 'a decimal constant'".

Comment: @Fred: it's normative for specific cases where C++ says that what is said in C is true, obvious examples being the contents of most C headers. It is not the case in general that any definition made in C89 applies also to C++. I agree with you that in C++03 it *is* a decimal constant, I'm just pointing out that C++ only very tentatively defines "decimal constant" at all, in a comment stating an intention by comparison with C. I don't think they meant to use the phrase "decimal constant" in C++ at all, but they did and so we must deduce whatever meaning for it we can scrape together.

Answer (score 1):

For general C++ code, see [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5076090/509868).

In Visual Studio 2017 (and, I suspect, all other versions) `__LINE__` has type `long`.

I used the following code to discover it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template <typename T>
void print_type(T x)
{
    std::cout << x << " has type " << typeid(x).name();
}

int main()
{
    print_type(__LINE__);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

C11, footnote 177:

> The presumed source file name and line number can be changed by the `#line` directive.

Note: [ISO/IEC Directives, Part 2](https://www.iec.ch/members_experts/refdocs/iec/isoiecdir-2%7Bed7.0%7Den.pdf):

> Footnotes to the text of a document are used to give additional contextual information to a specific item in the text. The document shall be usable without the footnotes.

C11, 6.10.4 Line control:

> `# line digit-sequence new-line`
>
> The digit sequence shall not specify zero, nor a number greater than 2147483647.

C11, 5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types <limits.h>:

> Their implementation-defined values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign.
>
> maximum value for an object of type `long int`
>
> `LONG_MAX                 +2147483647 // 2^31 − 1`

Hence, I conclude that the maximum value of of `__LINE__` is guaranteed to fit into `long int`.